# Ubuntu 16.04 failing to suspend and opening applications by itself

Tags: suspend, touchpad, laptop, power-management

I have a very strange problem. After installing stock Ubuntu 16.04, I noticed that whenever I close the lip on my laptop and come back a few hours later, every application (on the launcher) is running and all the icons are mixed up. There are also new folders created on my desktop and even multiple instances of the same application running (up to 30)!! I'm the only one with access to this computer and it is set to suspend when the lid is shut.

I did install a desktop recording application and recorded what happens when the lid closes. The cursor jumps around sporadically clicking and dragging all over the screen. The computer never actually suspends either. Even if the lid is only closed for 10 seconds, that is enough to get a couple new folders created on the desktop.

The laptop is a HP Spectre x360.

I'm thinking it may be the touchpad, since I have had problems with it in the past, but nothing like this. Any advice on this would be appreciated.

Comment: I must agree with you; that is, indeed,  _very_ strange! Let's see if we can address the failure to suspend issue. First, is your system up to date? And second, do you have a swap partition?

Comment: Everything is up to date and I do have a swap partition of 8GB.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please open a terminal and post the output of the following command `sudo blkid | grep swap && cat /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` ?

Comment: Okay, so this is what I get: /dev/sda3: UUID="d3112441-f092-4027-ad6f-162d53b6de3d" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="198cdb8e-0cae-4041-9f0a-dc48ee95c112"
RESUME=UUID=d3112441-f092-4027-ad6f-162d53b6de3d

Comment: Ok, that looks good. The alpha-numeric strings between the quotes following `UUID=` match up, as they should. Let's try putting your computer to sleep _without_ closing the lid. In a terminal, can you please type `sudo pm-suspend`, which will put your computer to sleep; and then wake it back up by pressing the power button. Did your computer go to sleep? And did any applications open by themselves?

Comment: The computer does go to sleep fine and no applications have been opened.

Comment: I retract that, after suspending using the terminal, 14 hours later the next day, the same problem occurred. New folders and every application open.

Comment: Hmm, has anyone else had access to your computer during those 14 hours? I ask this because it is possible that somebody could wake your computer, open the programs and create folders, and then put it back to sleep. Also, can you please suspend your computer from the terminal, wake it 30 seconds later, and then let me know if any new programs have opened?

Comment: Nobody has access to this computer, but me. Even just today, it was suspended, in a closed bag with me for several hours and the same thing happened. If I suspend it from terminal and wake it after 30 sec, then it does not do anything out of the ordinary.